# Disable download for a specific file for a file share storage

Tags: azure, storage

ML Studio initialises with a blob and a file share storage. Where the file storage will be used for notebooks. My client would like the download option disabled to for the dataset that was uploaded to the file share. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, Azure files does not provide a way to restrict access to downloading a specific file, if the user has a key or SaS token for the storage account (or access to this through ML Studio) then they will be able to download the file.